# How to automatically create a torrent file for each folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, bittorrent, utorrent

I have several hundred folders I want to share using the torrent protocol.
The problem is that creating a file by using a GUI interface for each folder is a waste of time.
Anyone knows of a program that can do this OR a torrent client that can create torrents from CLI? That would be easily scriptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ctorrent (on sourceforge):

ctorrent -t -u tracker_url -s torrent_name source

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Thanks for finding this tool, have been looking for one.

Answer (score 0):

"MakeTorrent"   you can select the main folder , it will create a .torrent for each subfolder and then auto add them to your utorrent client and start seeeding